# Retrieve text files using minio s3 spring cloud config server

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud-config, minio, aws-s3-client, amazons3client

I am trying to fetch text files using config urls in my spring cloud config server.

The url format is: `http://localhost:8080/config-server-service/prod/test/test1.txt`
where, config-server is the name of the application server, prod is the profile, test is the folder name for minio bucket and test1.text is the filename.

Even though test1.txt and test1-prod.txt file exists inside test folder, i am getting an 404 error:

```
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: security_authentication=Fe26.2**a84f225ac3c9fa344b6d276dc2d142c67f4dc78543705577cd5c5de24f470b47*UijhHhd7tN6efBvaMszEng*rjAHa4KoTHd_NYeJW4M7Zqm8IuAgQ_wW8l88XYRLxVGQmIyDzvK6WUN3w5xzRnSrinNEJH8ZI6tVGUWYlZUYtLnNWd_CqZlXDOX1bYHc7u8btoBL7-KIsXyyWU837_ImcPhs8c8wZzHJwRrGBNpXtkMxeQBPIeH2G_-tsncE9blZLUesMRA9NWn9sOUJLN7xU2ByhTVYczatOwszGPnPzzKZlp9qOwY-hg5yFB9WdnQ**0f1695b96263093906fbc9a5ab0ef70b46ed18374a153738c0082b5ff762cd5c*v2HX3YWPQnTk4mAidQfIRRo_lQJFd8waWbNXYcRDhR0; JSESSIONID=6D14C332CC525CE613BAE2FEDAAE21C0

]
2023-11-08T15:43:40.286+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set query string encoding to UTF-8
2023-11-08T15:43:40.287+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: security_authentication=Fe26.2**a84f225ac3c9fa344b6d276dc2d142c67f4dc78543705577cd5c5de24f470b47*UijhHhd7tN6efBvaMszEng*rjAHa4KoTHd_NYeJW4M7Zqm8IuAgQ_wW8l88XYRLxVGQmIyDzvK6WUN3w5xzRnSrinNEJH8ZI6tVGUWYlZUYtLnNWd_CqZlXDOX1bYHc7u8btoBL7-KIsXyyWU837_ImcPhs8c8wZzHJwRrGBNpXtkMxeQBPIeH2G_-tsncE9blZLUesMRA9NWn9sOUJLN7xU2ByhTVYczatOwszGPnPzzKZlp9qOwY-hg5yFB9WdnQ**0f1695b96263093906fbc9a5ab0ef70b46ed18374a153738c0082b5ff762cd5c*v2HX3YWPQnTk4mAidQfIRRo_lQJFd8waWbNXYcRDhR0; JSESSIONID=6D14C332CC525CE613BAE2FEDAAE21C0
2023-11-08T15:43:40.288+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 6D14C332CC525CE613BAE2FEDAAE21C0
2023-11-08T15:43:40.289+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /config-server-service/prod/test/test1.txt
2023-11-08T15:43:40.289+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-11-08T15:43:40.292+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [/tmp/tomcat.8080.14180384723947386722/conf/jaspic-providers.xml]
2023-11-08T15:43:40.292+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-11-08T15:43:40.299+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-11-08T15:43:40.299+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/config-server-service/prod/test/test1.txt", parameters={}
2023-11-08T15:43:40.307+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController#retrieve(String, String, String, ServletWebRequest, boolean)
2023-11-08T15:43:40.322+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceControllerAdvice#notFound(NoSuchResourceException)
2023-11-08T15:43:40.322+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.NoSuchResourceException: Not found: test1.txt]
2023-11-08T15:43:40.322+05:30 DEBUG 214768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I have referred to the spring cloud config doc while setting up the project: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-config-serving-plain-text-aws-s3

I am using the standard endpoint format to fetch the files: /{application}/{profile}/{label}/{path}I have also tried setting up Accept header as application/octet-stream while making get request using urls but with no luck.

I am using the following versions:
Java version: 17
spring-cloud-version: 2022.0.4
s3: 2.20.52
spring-cloud-aws-context: 2.4.2
spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure: 2.2.6.RELEASE

Basically I want to fetch excel and text files from s3 server.Thanks